# Can I upgrade my iPhone from iOS 4.2.1 to iOS 5? iTunes only shows iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, upgrade, software-update

I have an iPhone 4 with iOS 4.2.1. I want to upgrade my iPhone to iOS 5, but iTunes will only let me upgrade the iPhone to iOS 6. I'd prefer not to, since many important apps don't work in India, especially Maps. Is it possible to upgrade my iPhone to iOS 5?

Answer (score 3):

You can download old versions of iOS [from this page](http://www.idownloadblog.com/iphone-downloads/) (the downloads are direct from Apple, this site just collects the links). Make sure to get the proper file for your phone (likely iPhone 4 (GSM)).

It's important to note that just having the old version isn't enough. Before installing any OS upgrades, the iPhone checks Apple's servers for an authorization code. Apple stops authorizing older versions some time after the next major version is released, so you may be out of luck.

You can try upgrading by going into iTunes, and **option-clicking** (shift-click in Windows) the **Update** button for your device. You should get a file dialog, from which you can select the `.ipsw` file you just downloaded. You should then be able to go through the usual updating process, assuming Apple authorizes it.